# Spring batch how can I force stop job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to stop job if the processor returned null
Examaple:

```
BatchStatus.failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to detected that an item processor returned null for an item, you can use the `org.springframework.batch.core.ItemProcessListener#afterProcess(Object item, Object result)`. The `result` parameter is the processing result and can be null if the processor returned null.

Now if you want to fail the job when the processor returns null, you can throw an exception from that method. Here is an example:

```
class MyItemProcessListener implements ItemProcessListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeProcess(Object item) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterProcess(Object item, Object result) {
        if (result == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failing job because processing of item " + item + " returned null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessError(Object item, Exception e) {

    }
}
```

If you use a fault tolerant chunk-oriented step, make sure the exception you throw from the listener is not configured as skippable or retryable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to throw a NullPinterException from ItemProcessListener to stop the job. The better approach would be to let spring batch automatically do for you. Say if your ItemReader is has read all of the data then return null from your ItemReader's read(). If ItemProcessor doesn't get anything to process, return null from your ItemProcessor's process(). Since ItemWriter is called with null, you won't have anything to write. Hence the spring batch would understand that all the records are read, processed and written. Hence the job would be stopped.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In that case, the job would finish with status COMPLETED having `filterCount` = number of items for which the processor returned null. The question was about having status = `BatchStatus.failed`. BTW, just a clarification: `Since ItemWriter is called with null,` null items returned by the processor are filtered out and are not sent to the writer.

Comment: Moreover, the question was about how to **force** the job to stop with status FAILED.